# Trigger a modal when user try to close browser's tab

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webapi

I'm using Angular 16 with TypeScript.
I have this method on my component which will open a modal:

```
canDeactivate(): Promise<boolean> {
if (this.canLeaveImportFlow) return new Promise<boolean>(() => true);
return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LeaveCardImportFlowModalComponent, {
    data: {
      title: this.leaveFlowTitle,
      content: this.leaveFlowContent,
      button: this.leaveFlowButton,
      confirmCallback: () => {
        this.canLeaveImportFlow = true;
        resolve(true); // Resolve promise with true if user clicks on the leave button
      }
    }
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
    resolve(false); // Resolve Promise with false if user close modal without confirming
  });
});
}
```

I want that when the user try to close the current browser tab, it will trigger that canDeactivate() method which will open a modal which has an X to close (which return false) and a button (which returns true), and based on the result let him close the tab or not.

I tried adding that event listener:

```
  @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
  onBeforeUnload(event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.canDeactivate().then((result: boolean) => {
      if (result) {
        // Consenti la chiusura del tab
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onBeforeUnload);
        event.returnValue = result; // Richiesto per alcuni browser
        window.close();
      }
    });
  }
```

But I get an error with window.close():

```
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.
```

If I remove that window.close(), the window won't close.

And other than that, before it opens my modal, I get the default alert from browser:
[image]

Comment: please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated, also generally, for browser close events, prefer the default chrome dialog that is seen the last screenshot!

Comment: I can't easily replicate that with stackblitz, because it involves opening a modal, some logic that return a value.. I'll try to do that if really needed

Comment: fair enough, go for the chrome browser default alert, that will solve your problem easily!

Comment: You can only show the default browser popup when unloading a page. You cannot show any custom content. This is to prevent malicous actors overriding the user's choice to leave the page, as was prevalent before this functionality was implemented,